# mysqli_fetch_all not retrieving records from one particular table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a MySQL db that I am accessing via a mysqli instance. All CRUD operations were working flawlessly until I exported the db and imported it onto a new server (using the new server now). Now, every table is working great and returning all records with a simple SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY ASC, except for one particular table where I am getting a completely empty response (not even an empty array, literally nothing at all) from this table while all the others return as expected.

The code is exactly the same for all tables with only the table name changed. Using WHERE to filter the results and obtain a single record works, I'm able to obtain a single filtered result as expected. Adding records to the table also works.

When copying and running the SQL queries directly in phpMyAdmin, I get the full table results just fine.

Tried using procedural methods rather than object oriented as well as iterating through results with while(), same result.

Both servers are running PHP 7.0, and in phpMyAdmin everything looks completely identical.

**Code removed at the advice of commenters.**

I'm really banging my head against the wall on this one.

Comment: SQL injections waiting to happen on this code..

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't publish this code, as Raymond indicated. But why don't you echo the constructed query to see what it looks like? Perhaps that will explain why there's no result. You could also test `$data` to see if it `=== false`, which means the query couldn't be executed, due to an error.

Comment: Happy to remove the code, but can I ask why? Just looking to learn.

Comment: Two things could be meant by Raymond and Kiko with _publishing_: 1) Bringing your web app to the _live_ status, e.g. to make it available online for www users. This is not recommended at this stage of your app, because your code is open to sql injections. E.g. you don't _prepare_ the sql statements (at least). See [this](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection) article. 2) Posting here, on stackoverflow, code that contains confidential informations, which should be kept only for your eyes, or for your company's users. Note that posts on SO are not permanently deleted. Though, the comments are.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @dakis! I definitely wouldn't put this live at all, it's way too early for that, I'm just getting the CRUD operations and data visualization set up right now. I read it as not putting my code in the question; there was certainly no important information, so I was a bit confused, but since this is my first time asking a question here I figured I'd follow the advice given.

Comment: I see no reason to have removed the code from your question. It doesn't contain anything confidential as far as I can tell. The data looks like sample data. How do I know? It's still visible in the revision history: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55524404/revisions

Comment: You are welcome. Indeed, you didn't have any sensible data. Though I wrote the 2nd point, so that you simply know it for the future. By the way, I suggest to use PDO instead of mysqli. Here a very good [tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo).

Answer (score 0):

After spending all morning on this, I figured it out a few minutes after posting here. Leaving it up in case anyone else runs into this issue since it was a real head-scratcher.

Somehow one of the records in the database became... Corrupted maybe is the right word? I started removing records one by one and as soon as I found the right one to remove, everything started working.

Hope that this helps someone else!